# Failed to build snap package: The linker version '2.23' used by the base 'core' is incompatible with files in this snap

Tags: snap, electron

I am trying to build a snap package of electron app by using `https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-installer-snap`, but it results in following error:

```
Priming desktop-gtk3
Files from the build host were migrated into the snap to satisfy dependencies that would otherwise not be met. This feature will be removed in a future release. If these libraries are needed in the final snap, ensure that the following are either satisfied by a stage-packages entry or through a part:
usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
The linker version '2.23' used by the base 'core' is incompatible with files in this snap:
    /tmp/electron-snap-9865iSlcEOI8HnOY/prime/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0.8.7 (2.25)
    /tmp/electron-snap-9865iSlcEOI8HnOY/prime/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.7 (2.25)
    /tmp/electron-snap-9865iSlcEOI8HnOY/prime/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpatw.so.1.6.7 (2.25)
    /tmp/electron-snap-9865iSlcEOI8HnOY/prime/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10 (2.25)
    /tmp/electron-snap-9865iSlcEOI8HnOY/prime/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.3.0 (2.26)
    /tmp/electron-snap-9865iSlcEOI8HnOY/prime/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0 (2.27)
Snapcraft failed (2)
(node:9865) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Exited with status 2
    at closeArgsToError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-installer-snap/node_modules/cross-spawn-promise/lib/index.js:20:16)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-installer-snap/node_modules/cross-spawn-promise/lib/index.js:76:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
(node:9865) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9865) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Why does this error occur? How to fix it?

[Edited]: Seems this is caused by incompatible nodejs library issue. Verified by [running `electron-installer-snap` in docker container ubuntu 16.04](https://github.com/artificerpi/electron-snap-builder).

Comment: Is this the same problem: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/the-linker-version-2-23-used-by-the-base-core-is-incompatible-with-files-in-this-snap/7430

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by running snapcraft inside an lxd-container

Install Snapcraft:

```
sudo snap install snapcraft
```

Install lxd

```
sudo addgroup --system lxd
sudo adduser $USER lxd
sudo snap install lxd
```

Build inside lxd-container

```
lxd init
export SNAPCRAFT_BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=lxd
snapcraft cleanbuild
```